# Inherit from a "sibling" class?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

Imagine I have:

```
class ABC():
  def main(self, x):
    self.x = x

class A(ABC):
  def afunction(self):
    self.a = 2

class B(ABC):
  def bfunction(self):
    self.b = self.a * self.x
    return self.b
```

How is it possible that class `B` inherits the `self.a` and `self.x` from class `A` and `ABC`? (I do not care about inheriting the methods)

Comment: Is B inherits from A, it'll inherit from ABC (son/father/grand father) To inherit from mutiple `class B(A, ABC)` , but what you may clarify your model structure to get something meaningful

Comment: Your wording is a bit confusing. Are you asking how to get B to inherit from A and ABC (that is, make `main` and `afunction` available in B)? If so, its just `class B(A):`. B will have A stuff and ABC stuff.

Comment: Tried to make it more clear, have a look

Comment: @Miguel You can't inherit instance attributes. This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: What _do_ you care about then — what's the point of doing so?

Comment: The literal answer to your question is that B doesn't inherit anything from A. Do you want B to inherit stuff from A and ABC?

Comment: A.afunction() always gets called first and then B.bfunction, and I want B to be able to access A.afunction self attributes dynamically

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Just have B inherit from A. `class B(A):`

Comment: Instance attributes aren't inherited; they either exist or they don't exist on the *instance*. Please provide a [mcve] that actually shows how `B` gets instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you want is to get B to inherit from A.
Notice that what will happen is that it will inherit A variables, and because A inherits from ABC, B will inherit ABC's variables as well.

Also, please note that you will have to initialize the x variable for example inside an B object in order to use the bFunction, and in general it is proper coding to set a constructor as follows:

```
class ABC():
    def __init__(self, x=0):
        self.x = x

    def main(self, x):
        self.x = x

class A(ABC):
    def __init__(self, a=2):
        super().__init__()
        self.a = a

    def afunction(self):
        self.a = 2

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, b=0):
        super().__init__()
        self.b = b

    def bfunction(self):
        self.b = self.a * self.x
        return self.b

b = B()
b.main(3)
b.afunction()
print(b.bfunction())
```

Output:

```
6
```

Comment: Is this possible without having the __init__ functions?

Comment: Yeah, you'll just need to set the x and b variables before with the afunction and main methods

Comment: Yes but how will the class B look like? super().__init__() does not make sense anymore does it?

Comment: Yep, you'll just need to erase all of the init functions, but just so you know that this is the correct way to set a class, depends on what you're trying to do of course.

Answer (score 0):

If B inherits from A, which inherits from ABC, then B will have ABC and A's methods but neither the 'x' or 'a' attributes which are only set after the methods are run. This works if you rewrite B as:

```
class B(A):
  def bfunction(self, x):
    self.main(x)
    self.afunction()
    self.b = self.a * self.x
    return self.b

b = B()
print(b.bfunction(10))
```

You have to supply 'x' to b.bfunction so that `self.b = self.a * self.x` works.